# Lookup Filter is not working

Tags: lookup-filter

I created filter Lookup :

(Sales Order Customer Ship To: Record TypeEQUALSShip To) AND ((Sales Order Customer Ship To: Company IDEQUALSPurchase Agreement: Sales Order Company ID) OR (Sales Order Customer Ship To: Company IDEQUALS))

In the record if i search on : Sales Order Customer Ship To: field i am able to see all value having ship to , Bill to, Sold to.

As per the filter criteria i am only able to save value having Ship to which is fine.

I want to know is there a way i can restrict that only Ship to fields are visible for search not all ?

Answer (score 1):

The records which are displayed on lookup page are the ones which were viewed recently. Lookup filters validates the data only when the record is saved. So, if the user has the access to the records and has viewed recently, then those records will be displayed on lookup page irrespective of the lookup filter (unless user searches for something in input box).

Currently, there is no way to restrict recently visited records from lookup page. [Here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxgoAAA) is the idea for the same (merged with few others) which is in development by salesforce and might be delivered in a couple of releases.